# Загрузка нескольких фотографий на сервер.

Tags: php, html

Как реализовать передачу нескольких изображений за раз на сервер?

Делал так. Ставил инпут для выбора фотографии. Если пользователь хочет загрузить еще фотографию, то нажимает на клавишу, js строит еще один инпут. 
Но потом заметил, что если скрипт(обработчик) не срабатывает, или надо его перезагрузить с этими же параметрами, то сохраняется только первый инпут. 
Как этого избежать? И какие другие методы для загрузки нескольких изображений имеются?

Comment: Вы скорее всего не массив изображений отправляете к обработчику?

Comment: нет. несколько изображений. Как в хтмл выбрать массив?

Comment: И какие другие методы для загрузки нескольких изображений имеются?

Comment: http://blog.kron0s.com/multiple_input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не пойму при чем тут загрузка "*фотографий на сервер*". С помощью JS вы встраиваете в DOM новый элемент (*input*), но на самом деле, на странице он не прописан и находиться там, как бы виртуально. Естественно, что при перезагрузке его опять не существует. Выходов из этой ситуации несколько: использовать куки, сессии, local storage и т.д.